# Haskell division algorithm function

Tags: haskell

my professor assigned me a pretty basic lab that is mostly done. Essentially what it should do resembles divMod. It should output the quotient and the remainder using a recursive function. Below is the code. I am not quite sure what is going on syntax wise also if someone could maybe explain what might go in the "Fill this in" part. I understand that a < b is the simple case meaning the quotient is zero and the remainder is a. So q = 0 and r = a. This will eventually be achieved by repeatedly subtracting b from a. Let 17 be a and 5 be b, so as follows: 17-5=12 then 12-5=7 then 7-5=2 which means the quotient is 3 and remainder is 2. So I understand whats going on I just cannot write it in haskell. Thanks for any help. Sorry for the super lengthy question.

```
divalg :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
divalg a b | a < b = --Fill this in--
           | otherwise = let (q, r) = divalg (a - b) b 
            in --Fill this in--
```

Comment: That doesn't look mostly done to me =P.  What have you attempted to do to fill in the blanks?  Do you have any pseudo code (it doesn't have to be correct Haskell)?  Can you outline the algorithm first?  The `a < b` case looks like it's probably your stop condition, what do you think it should return for `divalg 2 3`?

Comment: Please give us more examples, i don't really understand what you needed (as my answer was downvoted?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the type signature, you can see that `divalg` takes two `Int`s and returns a pair of `Int`s, which you correctly identified as the quotient and remainder. Thus in the base case (where `a < b`), you should do that: return a tuple containing the quotient and remainder.

In the recursive case, the recursive call is already written. When thinking about recursion, assume the recursive call "does the right thing". In this case, the "right thing" is to return the quotient and remainder of `(a-b)/b`. I'll leave the math to you, but the basic idea is that you need to modify the tuple `(q,r)` to get a new tuple containing the quotient/remainder for `a/b`. How do I know this is the right thing to do? Because the type signature told me so.

In short, your code will look something like this:

```
| a < b = (___, ___)
| otherwise = let ...
 in (___, ___)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for such a noobish question. Haskell is just foreign to me. Makes perfect senses now I understand how to work with tuples much better now.